# Not able to find the grid.jqueryui.js?

Tags: jqgrid

How can I add this javascript file to demostrate the online demo?

[JQGRID LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/santoshgiridhar/JC8CT/1/)

Not able to do column-re-ordering?

```
sortable: true
rownumbers:true,
search:true,
    scroll:1, 
    pager: '#pcolr',
sortname: 'invdate',
viewrecords: true,
sortorder: "asc",
caption:"Column Reordering Example with toolbar search"
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated the missing jQueryUI JavaScript library link!

[Updated link](http://jsfiddle.net/santoshgiridhar/JC8CT/7/)

```
    rownumbers:true,
rowNum:10,
search:true,
scroll:1, 
pager: '#pcolr',
sortname: 'id',
viewrecords: true,
sortorder: "asc",
```